# DPDK how polling is done?

Tags: dpdk

What I understand about DPDK is that the ring buffer of NIC gets mapped to userspace address and data in there gets processes on a polling basis. (Please correct me if wrong)

For that, how is periodic polling carried out? Is there any process running in the background that periodically causes polling, through API provided by PMD(polling mode driver)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polling is done straightforward in a loop, i.e.:

```
main() {
    // Init ports
    ...
    // Main loop
    while(!quit_flag) {
        // Receive a burst of packets (poll)
        nb_rx = rte_eth_rx_burst(...);

        // Process packets
        ...

        // Send a burst of packets
        rte_eth_tx_burst(..., nb_rx);
    }
}
```

Sure, it could be done on a separate thread(s) (in DPDK we call them lcores), but the idea stays the same: the application model is up to the developer.

There are lots of examples in the [DPDK repo](https://github.com/DPDK/dpdk/blob/master/examples/l2fwd/main.c#L221)

DPDK also has a few frameworks to facilitate an implementation of an event-driven or pipeline application architecture.

For more details see [DPDK Programmers Guide](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/prog_guide/)